# Forward CiviEvent Registration Confirmation and Receipt

Tags: civievent, email

Apologies for such a basic question but I can't figure out how to do this. I want to forward the CiviEvent Registration Confirmation and receipt to a different email address than the email of the person who registered. I tried editing the event registration and going through the activities of that person and I'm not seeing where I could do this.

Comment: Is this a one off or a for all participants for a specific event or event template?

Answer (score 1):

You can include additional email address in the CC or BCC field while configure the event. On the “Online Registration “ tab, at the very bottom, in confirmation email section.